# Not able to type in reactsJs input fields

Tags: reactjs, input, use-state

Issue: In Value and SomeOtherValue Component's input tag, not able to type more than one input, it looses focus after each character it is happening, I think use of switch case in Builder component is creating this issue, but don't understand how, and not sure what could be solution to this problem..

code link:https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-breeze-upubj?file=/src/

Comment: There's a bug on your codesandbox code, it crashes

Comment: @IamL try this link https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-breeze-upubj?file=/src/Command.js

Comment: ah it re-renders when you type because you are storing the "component" inside the state. What you can do is transfer the state handling inside the Builder Component.

Comment: Callback function will not work for state variable (Command component) that I am using inside the return. is there any solution for this

Comment: yes, do the state change inside the `Builder` component instead of directly changing the value from the parent component.

Comment: I have moved state change to builder, but issue is now that "component" variable in the return part of the command component as it using map function also. not sure how will I get data in side it, do i have to create new variable and assign value to it using callback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223268/discussion-between-kartikeya-and-i-am-l).

Comment: you don't have to update the `component` variable from parent coz you are already updating the value directly inside the component. Which means that you don't have to pass the `value` as a prop.